# Адаптивность. Как сделать чтобы блоки одностраничника в телефоне шли вертикально друг под другом?

Tags: html, css, адаптивность

как сделать чтобы блоки для телефона шли вертикально подряд друг под другом[image: По типу этого]

https://codepen.io/1rocky12/pen/WNxgvKo

```js
// portfolio
 $('.gallery ul li a').click(function() {
     var itemID = $(this).attr('href');
     $('.gallery ul').addClass('item_open');
     $(itemID).addClass('item_open');
     return false;
 });
 $('.close').click(function() {
     $('.port, .gallery ul').removeClass('item_open');
     return false;
 });

 $(".gallery ul li a").click(function() {
     $('html, body').animate({
         scrollTop: parseInt($("#top").offset().top)
     }, 400);
 });
```

```css
* {
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
*:before, *:after {
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  font-family: "Lato", sans-serif;
  font-weight: 300;
  line-height: 1.5;
  color: #333;
}

a {
  color: #fff;
}

.row {
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 1170px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 0;
  clear: both;
}
.row img {
  max-width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

.gallery ul li {
  float: left;
  margin: 0 0.8771929825%;
  overflow: hidden;
}

header {
  background-color: #84b4b1;
  color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 30px 0 120px;
}
header h1 {
  text-align: center;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-size: 65px;
  font-weight: 400;
  letter-spacing: 3px;
  line-height: 0.8;
  padding-top: 50px;
  font-family: "Montserrat", sans-serif;
}
header h1 span {
  text-transform: uppercase;
  letter-spacing: 7px;
  font-size: 25px;
  line-height: 1;
}
header p {
  padding-top: 30px;
}

.gallery {
  padding: 40px 0 300px;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.gallery ul {
  padding-top: 50px;
  position: relative;
}
.gallery ul li {
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  width: 23.2456140351%;
  position: relative;
}
.gallery ul li a {
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  line-height: 0;
}
.gallery ul li a:before {
  position: absolute;
  width: 32px;
  height: 32px;
  top: 40%;
  left: 50%;
  margin: -14px 0 0 -16px;
  background: url(data:image/svg+xml;utf8,%3C%3Fxml%20version%3D%221.0%22%20encoding%3D%22utf-8%22%3F%3E%0A%3C%21--%20Generator%3A%20Adobe%20Illustrator%2017.1.0%2C%20SVG%20Export%20Plug-In%20.%20SVG%20Version%3A%206.00%20Build%200%29%20%20--%3E%0A%3C%21DOCTYPE%20svg%20PUBLIC%20%22-//W3C//DTD%20SVG%201.1//EN%22%20%22http%3A//www.w3.org/Graphics/SVG/1.1/DTD/svg11.dtd%22%3E%0A%3Csvg%20version%3D%221.1%22%0A%09%20id%3D%22svg2%22%20xmlns%3Adc%3D%22http%3A//purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/%22%20xmlns%3Acc%3D%22http%3A//creativecommons.org/ns%23%22%20xmlns%3Ardf%3D%22http%3A//www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns%23%22%20xmlns%3Asvg%3D%22http%3A//www.w3.org/2000/svg%22%20xmlns%3Asodipodi%3D%22http%3A//sodipodi.sourceforge.net/DTD/sodipodi-0.dtd%22%20xmlns%3Ainkscape%3D%22http%3A//www.inkscape.org/namespaces/inkscape%22%20inkscape%3Aversion%3D%220.48.4%20r9939%22%20sodipodi%3Adocname%3D%22icon-fullscreen.svg%22%0A%09%20xmlns%3D%22http%3A//www.w3.org/2000/svg%22%20xmlns%3Axlink%3D%22http%3A//www.w3.org/1999/xlink%22%20x%3D%220px%22%20y%3D%220px%22%20viewBox%3D%220%200%20960%20560%22%0A%09%20enable-background%3D%22new%200%200%20960%20560%22%20xml%3Aspace%3D%22preserve%22%3E%0A%3Csodipodi%3Anamedview%20%20borderopacity%3D%221%22%20pagecolor%3D%22%23ffffff%22%20bordercolor%3D%22%23666666%22%20objecttolerance%3D%2210%22%20gridtolerance%3D%2210%22%20guidetolerance%3D%2210%22%20showgrid%3D%22false%22%20fit-margin-top%3D%220%22%20fit-margin-left%3D%220%22%20inkscape%3Azoom%3D%227.375%22%20inkscape%3Acx%3D%22-5.1525424%22%20inkscape%3Acy%3D%2216%22%20id%3D%22namedview11%22%20inkscape%3Awindow-x%3D%22-8%22%20inkscape%3Awindow-y%3D%22-8%22%20fit-margin-right%3D%220%22%20inkscape%3Apageopacity%3D%220%22%20fit-margin-bottom%3D%220%22%20inkscape%3Awindow-width%3D%221366%22%20inkscape%3Awindow-height%3D%22706%22%20inkscape%3Awindow-maximized%3D%221%22%20inkscape%3Apageshadow%3D%222%22%20inkscape%3Acurrent-layer%3D%22svg2%22%3E%0A%09%3C/sodipodi%3Anamedview%3E%0A%3Cg%3E%0A%09%3Crect%20x%3D%22220%22%20y%3D%22260%22%20fill%3D%22%23FFFFFF%22%20width%3D%22536%22%20height%3D%2224%22/%3E%0A%3C/g%3E%0A%3Cg%3E%0A%09%3Crect%20x%3D%22476%22%20y%3D%224%22%20fill%3D%22%23FFFFFF%22%20width%3D%2224%22%20height%3D%22556%22/%3E%0A%3C/g%3E%0A%3C/svg%3E%0A) no-repeat;
  content: "";
  opacity: 0;
  z-index: 1;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.3s linear;
  -moz-transition: all 0.3s linear;
  transition: all 0.3s linear;
}
.gallery ul li a:hover:before {
  top: 50%;
  opacity: 1;
}
.gallery ul li a:after {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
  content: "";
  opacity: 0;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.3s linear;
  -moz-transition: all 0.3s linear;
  transition: all 0.3s linear;
}
.gallery ul li a:hover:after {
  opacity: 1;
}

.port {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  padding-top: 100px;
  background: #ffffff;
  background-color: #fafafa;
  z-index: 103;
  visibility: hidden;
  -webkit-transform: translateY(-100%);
  transform: translateY(-100%);
  border-bottom: 1px solid #d0d0d0;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
  transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
}
.port img {
  width: 50%;
}
.port .description {
  float: left;
  width: 50%;
  max-height: 100%;
  padding: 0 40px 40px;
  overflow: auto;
}
.port h1 {
  font-size: 35px;
  line-height: 2.3;
  padding: 0;
}
.port > * {
  opacity: 0;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.5s linear;
  -moz-transition: all 0.5s linear;
  transition: all 0.5s linear;
}
.port.item_open {
  visibility: visible;
  -webkit-transform: translateY(0%);
  transform: translateY(0%);
  -webkit-transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out;
  transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out;
}
.port > * {
  opacity: 1;
  -webkit-transition-delay: 0.5s;
  transition-delay: 0.5s;
}

.close {
  width: 21px;
  height: 21px;
  background: url(data:image/svg+xml;utf8,%3C%3Fxml%20version%3D%221.0%22%20encoding%3D%22utf-8%22%3F%3E%0A%3C%21--%20Generator%3A%20Adobe%20Illustrator%2017.1.0%2C%20SVG%20Export%20Plug-In%20.%20SVG%20Version%3A%206.00%20Build%200%29%20%20--%3E%0A%3C%21DOCTYPE%20svg%20PUBLIC%20%22-//W3C//DTD%20SVG%201.1//EN%22%20%22http%3A//www.w3.org/Graphics/SVG/1.1/DTD/svg11.dtd%22%3E%0A%3Csvg%20version%3D%221.1%22%0A%09%20id%3D%22svg2%22%20xmlns%3Adc%3D%22http%3A//purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/%22%20xmlns%3Acc%3D%22http%3A//creativecommons.org/ns%23%22%20xmlns%3Ardf%3D%22http%3A//www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns%23%22%20xmlns%3Asvg%3D%22http%3A//www.w3.org/2000/svg%22%0A%09%20xmlns%3D%22http%3A//www.w3.org/2000/svg%22%20xmlns%3Axlink%3D%22http%3A//www.w3.org/1999/xlink%22%20x%3D%220px%22%20y%3D%220px%22%20viewBox%3D%220%200%2021%2021%22%0A%09%20enable-background%3D%22new%200%200%2021%2021%22%20xml%3Aspace%3D%22preserve%22%3E%0A%3Cg%20id%3D%22layer1%22%20transform%3D%22translate%280%2C-1031.3622%29%22%3E%0A%09%3Cpath%20id%3D%22path2987%22%20fill%3D%22none%22%20stroke%3D%22%23000000%22%20d%3D%22M0%2C1031.4l21%2C21%22/%3E%0A%09%3Cpath%20id%3D%22path2989%22%20fill%3D%22none%22%20stroke%3D%22%23000000%22%20d%3D%22M21%2C1031.4l-21%2C21%22/%3E%0A%3C/g%3E%0A%3C/svg%3E%0A%0A) no-repeat;
  position: absolute;
  right: 10px;
  top: -121px;
  opacity: 1;
  z-index: 1004;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.1s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: all 0.1s ease-in-out;
  transition: all 0.1s ease-in-out;
}
.item_open .close {
  opacity: 1;
  top: 0px;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
  transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" >
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>CodePen - Balkan Style - Portfolio Gallery</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/meyer-reset/2.0/reset.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="./style.css">

</head>
<body>
<!-- partial:index.partial.html -->
<link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat:400,700' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
    <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato:300' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>


<header>
    <h1>Дмитрий <br> <span>[ МОИ ДОСТИЖЕНИЯ ]</span></h1>
</header>

<div id="top"></div>
<section class="gallery">
    <div class="row">
        <ul>
            <a href="#" class="close"></a>
            <li>
                <a href="#item02">
                    <img src="https://cdn.dribbble.com/users/545884/screenshots/3981307/lorena2.png" alt="">
                </a>
            </li>

            <li>
                <a href="#item02">
                    <img src="https://cdn.dribbble.com/users/545884/screenshots/3892302/contact.png" alt="">
                </a>
            </li>

            <li>
                <a href="#item02">
                    <img src="https://cdn.dribbble.com/users/545884/screenshots/4154721/dive--001.png" alt="">
                </a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a class="image" href="#item01">
                    <img src="https://cdn.dribbble.com/users/545884/screenshots/4356121/darko--dr.jpg" alt="">
                </a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a class="image" href="#item02">
                    <img src="https://cdn.dribbble.com/users/545884/screenshots/3695553/news.png" alt="">
                </a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a class="image" href="#item01">
                    <img src="https://cdn.dribbble.com/users/545884/screenshots/4360101/liberosis_--_12.png" alt="">
                </a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a class="image" href="#item01">
                    <img src="https://cdn.dribbble.com/users/545884/screenshots/3148799/technical-book.jpg" alt="">
                </a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a class="image" href="#item01">
                    <img src="https://cdn.dribbble.com/users/545884/screenshots/2883479/cover.jpg" alt="">
                </a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div> <!-- / row -->

    <!-- Item 01 -->
    <div id="item01" class="port">
    
        <div class="row">
            <div class="description">
                <h1>Item 01</h1>
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vivamus quis libero erat. Integer ac purus est. Proin erat mi, pulvinar ut magna eget, consectetur auctor turpis.</p>
            </div>

                <img src="https://cdn.dribbble.com/users/545884/screenshots/3981307/lorena2.png" alt="">
            </div>
        </div> <!-- / row -->

    </div> <!-- / Item 02 -->

    <!-- Item 02 -->
    <div id="item02" class="port">
    
        <div class="row">
            <div class="description">
                <h1>Item 02</h1>
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vivamus quis libero erat. Integer ac purus est. Proin erat mi, pulvinar ut magna eget, consectetur auctor turpis.</p>
            </div>
            <img src="https://cdn.dribbble.com/users/545884/screenshots/2883479/cover.jpg" alt="">
        </div> <!-- / row -->

    </div> <!-- / Item 02 -->

</section> <!-- / projects -->
<!-- partial -->
  <script src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js'></script><script  src="./script.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

У вас есть фрагмент css:

```
.gallery ul li {
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    width: 23.2456140351%;
    position: relative;
}
```

То есть вы явно задаёте элементам списка `li` ширину в 23 с небольшим процента. Уберите и они станут занимать всю ширину или задайте эту ширину в тех же процентах, но больше 50% тогда больше одного в строке их не поместится.

P. S. Задавать значение с десятью знаками после запятой - так себе идея. Округляйте.

Comment: Как добавить медиа-запрос? Я добавлял это, но не работает: @media screen and (max-width: 500px){
  .gallery ul li{
    width: 23.25%;
  }
}

Comment: `@media screen... ` запрос для экранов, то есть не для мобильных устройств, ну и ширину надо указывать не как четверть ширины, а или 100% иби больше 50%, чтобы больше одного li в строку не помещалось.

Comment: Тогда что вместо screen использовать, чтобы поддерживались мобильные устройства?

Comment: Бог с ним, со скрином, ширину укажите верно.

Comment: У меня все получилось, но я хочу чтобы так выглядело мобильная версия сайта.

Comment: Скорее всего, так она и будет выглядеть. Посмотрите на сайт с экрана, но в режиме мобильных устройств. Скорее всего, всё должно выглядеть как надо. Впрочем, хорошо бы проверить именно на мобильном устройстве или нескольких.

Comment: Да все так и выглядит. Но я хочу чтобы на пк была первая версия, а на телефоне вертикально вниз блоки. Медиа запросы не хотят работать.

Comment: Вам просто нужны запросы как для мобильной версии, вы написали для `(max-width: 500px)`, а теперь надо написать что-то вроде `(min-width: 600px)` то есть от 600 пикселей и выше и уснова укажите ваши 23 с небольшим процента ширины.

Comment: Я сделал, но не совсем получилось. При 500 блоки не хотят становится вертикально вниз https://codepen.io/1rocky12/pen/KKMxNRW

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/115921/discussion-between-rocky-and-quazimorda).